# Linux Different Distribution Commands

Tags: linux, system-administration

Hi I am a Linux Beginner, While reading Linux I found three types of commands doing the same job **service,chkconfig,systemctl** I know these are differ from distribution to distribution . can anyone suggest how to learn these command for different distribution.

Especially how to remember :)

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to [so], please post this question on https://superuser.com/ ... please read [mcve] for both to figure out what kind of questions belong where. This way you will get good answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
man service
man chkconfig
man systemctl
```

or Google:

https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=man+service

https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=man+chkconfig

https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=man+systemctl